# Why usb3.1 Type-C has two Dbus, RXbus and TXbus?

Tags: usb

So I am using a camera and making it connect to a hub. The hub only has 9 pins(single Dbus, RXbus and TXbus) while camera has usb3.1 which has double if all these buses (D,RX and TX). So to connect it to a hub can I just short these two buses. What should I do?

USB ports:

[image]

Hub ports:

[image]

Comment: There's only one of each bus. For example, TX1+ & TX2+ on pins A2 & B2 are connected together on your PCB - same for all the other bus lines (TX-, RX+/- D+/-). They're duplicated in order to make the connector reversible.

Comment: @brhans Tx1 and Tx2 are not connected together on mainboards. They are connected to different ports of a MUX, and the host port switches the pairs depending on plug orientation (per CC pin state), D+ and D- are, however, different, A6-B6 and A7-B7 are connected, true.

Comment: There are actually two independent RX and TX channels (hence, 1 and 2).  For normal USB3.1, only one of the channel pairs is used.  For USB3.2 both pairs can be used to double throughput (so called 1x2 and 2x2 mode).  Do not connect them together.

Comment: I don't need it for both side use so I will use only RX1,SX1 and one Dbus. But what about CC and SBU pins. No idea what are they. After reading a little CC1 on usb hub should be pulled-up as it is taking data from camera and so is downstream. Can I just leave CC2 pin and SBU1/2 pins floating?